# get non repeating random numbers from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, numbers, repeat

I'm making a quiz. 
I try to find a way to generate non repeating random numbers from an array. How can help me?

This is what I have:

```
questions = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7"]
var randoms001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
```

Comment: Can you provide the language please? Is it `javascript`?

Comment: Yes it's javascript, forgot to mention it.

Comment: First shuffle the array, then pick as many entries as you need from the front.  Assuming the array has no duplicates then the entries you pick will not repeat.  I don't know if Javascript has a built-in shuffle.  If not, then write a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) method for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle the array and loop through it.

```js
var questions = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7"];
var shuffledQuestions = randoSequence(questions);

for(var i = 0; i < shuffledQuestions.length; i++){
  console.log( shuffledQuestions[i].value );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

I used [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to do the shuffle in a simple and readable way, but feel free to [shuffle it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array) if you that's your preference.

If you choose to use randojs, just make sure this is in the head of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```